# If $A$ is a real-valued matrix with $A^T A = AA^T$ then are the eigenvalues of $A$ necessarily real?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

If $A$ is a real-valued matrix with $A^T A = AA^T$, then are the eigenvalues of $A$ real?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Take $A=\begin{pmatrix}0&-1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}\ $ as a counterexample.